# Select Unique Value from Values Returned in a Query

Tags: sql, max

I have a table with data like this:

| item | due_date | net_avail_qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03-APR-21 | 11 |
| 1 | 05-APR-21 | -3 |
| 1 | 01-MAY-21 | 6 |
| 1 | 13-JUN-21 | 8 |
| 2 | 05-APR-21 | 99 |
| 2 | 07-MAY-21 | 81 |
| 2 | 11-MAY-21 | 72 |
| 2 | 13-JUL-21 | 60 |
| 2 | 23-JUL-21 | 55 |
| 5 | 12-APR-21 | 22 |
| 5 | 06-MAY-21 | 5 |
| 5 | 14-MAY-21 | 12 |

I have figured out this query:

```sql
SELECT item, MAX(due_date) 
FROM *table* 
where item = '1' 
GROUP BY item, TRUNC(due_date, 'MM')
```

I get this:

| item | MAX(due_date) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 05-APR-21 |
| 1 | 01-MAY-21 |
| 1 | 13-JUN-21 |

This is partially what I want, but it limits me to only item 1 and if I  try to add net_avail_qty to the query I return all values -- probably because the net_avai_qty values are all different.

What I want to end up with is this:

| item | due_date | net_avail_qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 05-APR-21 | -3 |
| 1 | 01-MAY-21 | 6 |
| 1 | 13-JUN-21 | 8 |
| 2 | 05-APR-21 | 99 |
| 2 | 11-MAY-21 | 72 |
| 2 | 23-JUL-21 | 55 |
| 5 | 12-APR-21 | 22 |
| 5 | 14-MAY-21 | 12 |

How would I go about doing this?  I have attempted subqueries but am not having luck.

Comment: I am not seeing the difference between the initial table, and the data you want to end up with.  Are you trying to see the total `net_avail_qty` on a per month basis?

Comment: Also please tag the database you are using.

Comment: The table I am querying as columns item, order_qty, due_date and net_avail_qty (amongst others) in it.  There are a lot of transactions occurring and the net_avail_qty is keeping the net result and positive and negative order_qty's are entered.  The order_qty is a positive if more are bought, negative if some are sold.  I want to find the balance in the net_avail_qty and the last date in that month for each item.  The initial query gives me the correct last dates.  When I try to add net_avail_qty to that query I get multiple dates in a month.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like Oracle, if so, you can use the `keep` syntax:

```
SELECT item, MAX(due_date),
       MAX(net_avail_qty) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY due_date DESC) as net_avail_qty
FROM *table* 
-- WHERE item = 1 
GROUP BY item, TRUNC(due_date, 'MM');
```

More commonly, though, I would say this is done using window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item, TRUNC(due_date, 'MM') ORDER BY due_date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM T
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Yes, this is Oracle.  Your suggestion with the KEEP syntax worked perfectly!  I want to try the windows function suggestion too but am not certain I understand where in that example I'd end up with the net_avail_qty.  I am also unsure where to put the tablename.  I REALLY appreciate your suggestion and help!!!

Comment: I found this code on another post.  Seems less efficient that what you suggested.  It does work though.  Is it less efficient to join a table to itself?  SELECT tt.*
FROM topten tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT home, MAX(datetime) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM topten
    GROUP BY home) groupedtt 
ON tt.home = groupedtt.home 
AND tt.datetime = groupedtt.MaxDateTime

Comment: @MMITSCH . . . That is less efficient than either of these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    a.item, b.max_due_date, a.net_avail_qty
FROM
    table1 a,
    (SELECT 
        item, MAX(due_date) max_due_date
    FROM
        table1
    GROUP BY item , TRUNC(due_date, 'MM')) b
WHERE
    a.item = b.item
        AND a.due_date = b.max_due_date;
```

Comment: That ran but the answer returned was not what I expected.   Seems like it got the some of the information but skipped some months and assigned wrong net_avail_qty to incorrect dates in some cases.  I'm  trying to  understand now.  Thank you for your suggestion and I will let you know what I find.